# How to show auxiliary points for any curves defined in a pscustom?

Tags: pstricks

I need to show the auxiliary points of any curves defined in `pscustom` such that I can easily locate the points during the development process.

The following MWE is my attempt to show such points, but fails.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1cm,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \pscustom[showpoints=true]
    {
        \psline(-4,-4)(-4,4)(4,4)(4,-4)
        \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1cm,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \pscustom{\psbezier[showpoints](-4,-4)(-4,4)(4,4)(4,-4)}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose you mean dots. Right? A line is a line, there are no auciliary points. If you want to see the dots use the coordinates also outside `\pscustom`: `\psdots(-4,-4)(-4,4)(4,4)(4,-4)`